# issue in flash pro cs6 - testing a mobile app

Tags: flash, flashdevelop, flash-cs6

Hey guys I have an app I am developing and it was being dev in flash pro CS5.5 but now it is being dev in CS6.  My issue is when I go to test it, it opens that terminates right away:

```
[SWF] pl.mllr.extensions.contactEditor - 8326 bytes after decompression
[SWF] soscs6.swf - 43323 bytes after decompression
[UnloadSWF] soscs6.swf
Test Movie terminated.
```

I don't know why it just shuts down right away?

If you could help I would appreciate!  Thank you :)

David

Answer (score 0):

I remember reading somewhere that Flash CS 5.5 had a publishing issue with FLAs. You can try two things:

- Create a new FLA in Flash CS6.
- See if you have LZMA enabled in the publishing settings. This is something that I found to be the culprit once.

If there's any more detail/Flash crash log you can provide, that'll help.